# make my machine invisible for ping

Tags: 12.04, python, security

I search solution to pevent my machine form the attack arp poisoning.

I believe to make my device invisible for this haker If they want to ping my machine they have any reply.

I don't khnow how I can use iptable to release it.or if they are a script python to do it to desable ping of devices.

I need help please.
thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to disable ICMP ping responses? There's no valid reason to do that as they pose no security risk on a system that was updated some time during the last decade. IPv6 mandates ICMP by the way. More info: http://www.netheaven.com/pmtu.html

Comment: You're talking about two different things, ping and arp responses.  Which one are you trying to block?  I don't think you really want to do either (a totally static arp table or just dropping icmp echo requests/replies).

Comment: I want to  prevent man in the middle speacial arp poisoin hacker for that I beleive to make my box invisible to do ping from the machine of  haker when I detect that presence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that without any external tools, simply by setting kernel variables.

Assuming that you are using IPV4 addresses, to disable ping responses:

```
sudo echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

To reenable ping responses:

```
sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

To disable icmp responses permanently, add this line to /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all = 1
```

**Please don't experiment any further with kernel variables. It can make your system unstable and loose important data.**

Comment: @ Hugo Vieira ,this command block all ping request I want to block ping request from some machine "some @ip "not all how should  I  do