Cannot ping my machine
My local machines is running on 192.168.1.136 ip address in my local wifi network. From another machine connected to the same network I tried to ping it but it doesn't get any answer. Thought it could be the firewall, I added the allowance of ICMP and TCP (port 80) to UFW and IPTABLES, but nothing changed. Currently UFW is disbaled, and I have read that pinging is activated my default.
I am completely lost as I have no more clues. Answers in https://askubuntu.com/a/112997/1886344 and https://askubuntu.com/a/598354/1886344 didn't solve my issue. Can anyone help me?

I'm on Ubuntu 24.04

Use tcpdump, or equivalent, to determine if the packets arrive at 192.168.1.136 and it is not responding, or if they don't arrive. For example sudo tcpdump -n -tttt -i enp3s0  icmp . Replace the interface name with your interface name. UFW being disabled doesn't flush its iptables rule set. Check with sudo iptables -xvnL
